# How to capture the native http network errors in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In JQuery AJAX while calling a REST API, As per the functionality the negative use cases needs to be logged.

In the chrome console this can be seen

```
net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

how to capture these exact errors in the error callback or any other means

The JQuery AJAX Code is

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: <my url>,
        contentType:'application/json',
        dataType:'text',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { },
        data: "",
        success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //success code
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(arguments);
            //here I need to capture the exact network error
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the developer tools -> network tab? This should hold everything about the call.

Comment: I want to programmatically capture whatever it is and store in SQLite offline database as log, so that in future if I see that log I can understand at what time the internet/wifi is disconnected

Comment: if you are only looking for online offline why not use the navigator.onLine?

Comment: But in case the server is not reachable, then also I should log the proper network error, navigator.online or offline is not yet fully realized in all browsers